# Java Swing layout not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm just getting into creating GUIs in Java, and with this basic setup, I can't get anything to appear in my JFrame:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    jframe.setSize(400,400); // setting size
    jframe.setVisible(true); // Allow it to appear
    jframe.setTitle("Lab 7");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Main init = new Main(); 
}  

 public Main() {
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton add = new JButton("Add");
    JButton close = new JButton("Close");
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area);

    add.setBounds(70, 125, 80, 20);
    close.setBounds(70, 115, 80, 20);
    pane.add(add);
    pane.add(close);
    pane.add(scroll);
    AddClick added = new AddClick();
    add.addActionListener(added);
}
}
```

I also tried moving all the JFrame stuff into public Main() but it caused an infinite amount of windows opening and I had to end the program each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating two separate `JFrame`s: one is your `Main` class, and the other is an unrelated `JFrame`. Most of the customization, including adding components, happens to the `Main` in its constructor. But you only ever set the other `JFrame` to be visible.

Use your `Main` instance as the `JFrame` instead of creating another one, and the problem will be fixed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jframe = new Main(); //Use an instance of Main as your JFrame
    jframe.setSize(400,400); // setting size
    jframe.setVisible(true); // Allow it to appear
    jframe.setTitle("Lab 7");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```